# Android 4.3 (x86) in Virtual Box recognize Bluetooth Dongle but don't activate Bluetooth

Tags: android, bluetooth, virtualbox

I've installed Android 4.3 (x86) in a VirtualBox VM, and I was trying to connect by Bluetooth, but it doesn't work. The VM recognize the Bluetooth Dongle but when I try to active Bluetooth in Settings menu doesn't work.

Could you help me?

Comment: Might be similar to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33272304/androidx86-usb-bluetooth-dongle-recognized-and-working-in-console-but-not-workin

Answer (score -1):

You are being extremely optimistic if you expect Android to be able to pick up a Bluetooth dongle while running in a virtual box. You would need an Android image specifically designed to do just that. A generic one just will not cut it.

Comment: Do you know if there is some Android image for that in any Web?

Comment: I very much doubt it. Is there any reason why you cannot use a real Android device?